# Why am I getting Error in trying to create a histograph? R says 'x' must be numeric, what does this mean?

Tags: r, histogram

Every time I try to create a histogram in R, it says:

```
Error in hist.default(csf.df$csf_recode) : 'x' must be numeric
```

What does this mean? I have tried removing the -99 variable and it's still popping up with this.

Comment: Hi @Michelle_Marcus, Welcome to SO! Can you add the results of ```str(csf.df)``` to your question? It sounds like your ```csf_recode``` variable may not be numeric (i.e. it may be character class instead).

Comment: Got it figured out, thanks!